# Kiosk mode on Firefox just like Chromium on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, raspberry-pi, chromium

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xset s noblank
xset s off
xset -dpms

unclutter -idle 0.5 -root &

sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

/usr/bin/chromium-browser --force-device-scale-factor=0.90 --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk localhost &

done
```

It does the following: It opens the browser on FULLSCREEN, and it disables the input of some keys like F11, along other things. So, the screen basically becomes just the browser content itself, without any visuals on it - It runs on fullscreen and it's difficult for the user to disable it, close the browser, etc.

My question is:
Is there anyway i can do the same thing but on Firefox?
I tried using the -kiosk option as [this documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode) said but it did'nt work.

Before someone says it: I only have Firefox installed on this OS and want to do this using Firefox, and not Chromium - So "Just uninstall firefox and install Chromium" isnt a solution...

**OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain "it did'nt work"? Also, this might be better to ask on SuperUser.com

Comment: Nothing happened - I executed "firefox -kiosk" and literally nothing happened on screen.

Comment: Ok ... Did you just write "firefox -kiosk" and it went straight to kiosk mode?

Comment: I just tried it on my Linux and Win boxes; *works on my machine*. I noticed you tagged this [tag:raspberry-pi], what windowing system are you using. Did you see the comment in the linked documentation: "Linux: Kiosk mode runs on Linux if the OS doesn't use a unified menu"?

Comment: I'm using a Raspberry PI and a Ubuntu 22.04. Neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to uninstall Firefox and install Chromium with snap.
Solved the problem and Chromium worked perfectly.